# For Typed Functions, with return Interface, is allowed to have non Interface's properties

Tags: typescript, function, interface

Imagine this interface:

```
interface IUser { 
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

We can have this function:

```
const fetchUser1 = (userId: string): IUser => { 
  return {
    id: userId,
    name: 'John',
    age: 32,
  };
}
```

This function cannot return properties that are not in the IUser interface.

So if we try to return for instance a new property the `city`:

```
const fetchUser2 = (userId: string): IUser => { 
  return {
    id: userId,
    name: 'John',
    age: 32,
    city: 'Hollabrunn', // TS Error
  };
}
```

We get the TS error: `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'city' does not exist in type 'IUser'` where is absolutely what we want.

Now let's try to make a Type for this function.

```
type TFetchUser = (userId: string) => IUser;
```

And implement a function of this Type, also returning by mistake the `city` property.

```
const fetchUser3: TFetchUser = (userId) => {
  return {
    id: userId,
    name: 'John',
    age: 32,
    city: 'Hollabrunn',
  };
};
```

**Now here is the problem, we don't have any TS Error.** The `city` property is allowed!

Although if we mistyped the `name` property to `fullName` we get the TS Error `Property 'name' is missing in type...`.

Googling, I found some references about this strange behavior of the interfaces, but not a clear resolution.

Could you help?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO1kG9kCwAUMssACYBcymYUoA5gNzGkhwC2E1t9IzrZHAbdkIAK4cARtBZEAvsWIIA9iFrIYEMAgAWWaAEZkAXmQAKcdiioqNOowCU1DNdMA+PIRLIo28VAgeIKkFNRW0LYANCFinKIA5ABSKrogCTE+pMKiAMwATJmk8nKKRMpqGlo6+tb5phYRNna8Ti4GUF6CfmABQbixYchN0bHsXNTJqelFpEIi1AWzpAjAYACekwASKgA2u3BSUOIgM8gA9OfIACoAysgAolBQKlBRyKrPEAhgAISCJWIZWIGwADihrgAxbR6DoNSzWWw8Bz8RweNAdOQVdRgTQw2rQahQ-FwswIyLkNEmTwDHw9PrBLJkOwjcjLOITZBTNIZWI5RaFWKrDbbPYHI4nM6XZAAOQA8jd7k8XlBfu9rro4GAEphkAB3F78AB0ANKciAA)

Comment: You should provide a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). I confirm it's incorrect typescript behavior

Comment: Playground link added

Comment: You're absolutely right that the inconsistency is weird but I believe you have it backwards: the first instance is wrong and the second correct. An object with the required properties does indeed implement `IUser` even if it has extra properties. Think about it this way, if the object were an instance of a class that implements IUser with a 'city' property it would still be type-safe. The interface says "you must do *at least* this much to conform", not "you can *only* do these three things".

Answer (score 1):

The spec ([3.11.5 Excess Properties](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3115-excess-properties)) mentions that checks for excess properties are only for direct assignment using *fresh object literals*.

In your first example, the object literal is directly attempting assignment to an IUser return type, which provokes the checking (and rightly raises an error), but in the second example you have an inserted step that may not be obvious at first.

Because the return type was unspecified, the function is inferred to have a return type of *that object literal*, not IUser, which means that the return statement is completely valid and no further checks are necessary.

The function is then assigned to a different type which requires a return type of IUser, which is assignment-compatible with your object, but by that time we're no longer talking about assigning an object literal and can safely ignore checks for excess properties.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jared Smith & Chris Hannon, the solution is defining the return type explicitly.

Otherwise, for TS, we *implement* the `IUser` and new properties are allowed in this case!

```
const fetchUser3: TFetchUser = (userId): IUser => {
  return {
    id: userId,
    name: 'John',
    age: 32,
    city: 'Hollabrunn',  // Now we have the TS Error here
  };
};
```